# How to define an EJB as default implementation when using inheritance?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, ejb-3.1, inject

I have the following situation:

```
@Stateless
public class ProjectManager{
    ...
}

@Stateless
public class ProjectManagerForLargeProjects extends ProjectManager{
    ...
}
```

So, this works fine when I try to inject the second manager

```
@Inject
private ProjectManagerForLargeProjects pMFLP;    // no problems, as expected
```

but when I try to inject the base ProjectManager the container doesn't know which implementation to choose.

```
@Inject
private ProjectManager pM;   // causes exception: WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [ProjectManager] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point ...
```

I know that I could use @Named to specify the implementations but I would just like to say ProjectManager is Default for ProjectManager.
Isn't there an easier way?

---

Solution: I used @EJB instead of @Inject and everything works as expected but why?

Comment: Use separate interfaces.  By the way, I think that the problems you are encountering are a strong indication for a code smell.

Comment: Hmm we're using a jee api which provides a stateless bean with some functionality and we want to add some functionality ... classical inheritance in my eyes, wouldn't I do this in JEE?

Comment: If composition is not an option for you, it might still be preferable to use two separate interfaces for the two use cases here (or make the distinction explicit by qualifiers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `@EJB` works for you here and `@Inject` doesn't is an artifact of how each annotation looks up dependencies.  EJB uses the bean name for resolution whereas Inject uses type hierarchies.  In this specific case Inject won't work for you without using qualifiers.